# Identifying and dropping SSL packets

Tags: ssl

I want to drop/block SSL packets between two machines (linux).
I can see the packets using ethereal and use iproute command (linux) to drop these packets.
Is this possible? If yes, what should I use with the iproute command?

Thanks.

Comment: Minor nit: We changed the name of the project from Ethereal to Wireshark in 2006. If you're still running Ethereal I strongly recommend that you upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You can't identify SSL packets at all by their contents, except for the first one in each direction. You could do it via the port number, as long as no form of START TLS was in use in the protocol, so it wouldn't work for SMTP, LDAP, etc. Otherwise you would have to follow entire TCP streams that start with a ClientHello.

Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to simulate a timeout (SSL handshake timeout) in my application so I though I could drop all SSL packets between the machines using iproute command.